# Fractal renderer in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, fractals

This was made mostly for fun, but also to practice.

I'm generally looking for feedback on how to make the code run faster, any obvious mistakes I'm making in regards to using WPF, which I'm not at all familiar with, and why the Complex class I made myself (and am not using) is so so much slower compared to the `System.Numerics` option.

Of course any other remarks are welcome as well, I'd love to know anything that could be improved upon, even if it's something small.

#### Fractal.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Numerics;

public class Fractal {
    static int width;
    static int height;
    static bool[] finished;
    static Complex[] originals, iterables;
    static int[] depths;
    static byte[] colors;
    static Complex center;
    static double radius;
    static Image image;
    static WriteableBitmap bitmap;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        image = new Image { Stretch = Stretch.None };
        Window window = new Window {
            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
            WindowState = WindowState.Maximized,
            ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize,
            Content = image
        };
        window.Show();
        width = (int) window.ActualWidth;
        height = (int) window.ActualHeight;

        bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
        image.Source = bitmap;
        Init(new Complex(-0.5, 0), 2);

        CompositionTarget.Rendering += (sender, e) => {
            Iterate();
            bitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), colors, width * 4, 0);
        };
        image.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) => {
            Init(originals[((int) e.GetPosition(image).Y) * width + ((int) e.GetPosition(image).X)], radius / 2);
        };
        window.KeyDown += (object sender, KeyEventArgs e) => {
            switch (e.Key) {
                case (Key.W):
                    Init(center + new Complex(0, -radius / (1 + 1.0 / width * height)), radius);
                    break;
                case (Key.A):
                    Init(center + new Complex(-radius / 2, 0), radius);
                    break;
                case (Key.S):
                    Init(center + new Complex(0, radius / (1 + 1.0 / width * height)), radius);
                    break;
                case (Key.D):
                    Init(center + new Complex(radius / 2, 0), radius);
                    break;
                case (Key.LeftShift):
                    Init(center, radius / 2);
                    break;
                case (Key.LeftCtrl):
                    Init(center, radius * 2);
                    break;
            }
        };

        Application application = new Application();
        application.Run();
    }

    static void Init(Complex c, double r) {
        int size = width * height;
        finished = new bool[size];
        originals = new Complex[size];
        iterables = new Complex[size];
        depths = new int[size];
        colors = new byte[size * 4];
        center = c;
        radius = r;
        Console.WriteLine("Center: " + c + "   Radius: " + r);

        Parallel.For(0, size, i => {
            int iColor = i * 4;
            int x = i % width;
            int y = i / width;
            originals[i] = new Complex(((x + 0.5) / width - 0.5) * 2 * radius, ((y + 0.5) / height - 0.5) * 2 / width * height * radius) + center;
            iterables[i] = new Complex(((x + 0.5) / width - 0.5) * 2 * radius, ((y + 0.5) / height - 0.5) * 2 / width * height * radius) + center; //Can start from (0, 0) in some cases.
            for (int offset = 0; offset < 4; offset++) {
                colors[iColor + offset] = 255;
            }
        });
    }

    static void Iterate() {
        Parallel.For(0, iterables.Length, i => {
            if (!finished[i]) {
                if (iterables[i].Magnitude > 2) { //Bounds
                    finished[i] = true;
                    Color(i); //Can pass the length to see how much over it went to create a smooth color gradient?
                } else {
                    //The equation
                    iterables[i] = iterables[i] * iterables[i] + originals[i];
                    //(new Complex(1, 0) - iterables[i] * iterables[i] + iterables[i] * iterables[i] * iterables[i] * iterables[i]) / (iterables[i] * 4 + 2) + SOMETHING;
                    //iterables[i] = iterables[i] * iterables[i] + 0.26;
                    depths[i]++;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //This needs a complete remake.
    static void Color(int i) { //Needs tweaking for prettier colors.
        byte r = 255, g = 255, b = 255;
        int speed = 2; //Lower values have smoother transitions, but are less colorful. (Powers of 2, preferably.)
        byte range = (byte) (256 / speed);
        byte gradient = (byte) (depths[i] % range);
        int paletteNo = (depths[i] / range) % 8;
        range--;

        switch (paletteNo) {
            case 0:
                r = 0;
                g = 0;
                b = gradient;
                break;
            case 1:
                r = 0;
                g = gradient;
                b = (byte) (range - gradient);
                break;
            case 2:
                r = 0;
                g = range;
                b = gradient;
                break;
            case 3:
                r = gradient;
                g = (byte) (range - gradient);
                b = (byte) (range - gradient);
                break;
            case 4:
                r = range;
                g = 0;
                b = gradient;
                break;
            case 5:
                r = range;
                g = gradient;
                b = (byte) (range - gradient);
                break;
            case 6:
                r = range;
                g = range;
                b = gradient;
                break;
            case 7:
                r = (byte) (range - gradient);
                g = (byte) (range - gradient);
                b = (byte) (range - gradient);
                break;
        }

        int iColor = i * 4;
        colors[iColor] = (byte) (b * speed);
        colors[iColor + 1] = (byte) (g * speed);
        colors[iColor + 2] = (byte) (r * speed);
    }
}
```

#### Complex.cs

```
using System;

public class Complex {
    double r, i;

    public Complex(double r, double i) {
        this.r = r;
        this.i = i;
    }

    public double Len() {
        return Math.Sqrt(r * r + i * i);
    }

    Complex Pair() {
        return new Complex(r, -i);
    }

    public static Complex operator +(Complex a, Complex b) {
        return new Complex(a.r + b.r, a.i + b.i);
    }

    public static Complex operator +(Complex a, double b) {
        return new Complex(a.r + b, a.i);
    }

    public static Complex operator -(Complex a, Complex b) {
        return new Complex(a.r - b.r, a.i - b.i);
    }

    public static Complex operator -(Complex a, double b) {
        return new Complex(a.r - b, a.i);
    }

    public static Complex operator *(Complex a, Complex b) {
        return new Complex(a.r * b.r - a.i * b.i, a.r * b.i + a.i * b.r);
    }

    public static Complex operator *(Complex a, double b) {
        return new Complex(a.r * b, a.i * b);
    }

    public static Complex operator /(Complex a, Complex b) {
        return a * (b.Pair() / b.Len());
    }

    public static Complex operator /(Complex a, double b) {
        return new Complex(a.r / b, a.i / b);
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return (r + "r, " + i + "i");
    }
}
```

Comment: Might have been better to post the WPF and Complex stuff in different questions; you should note that `System.Numerics.Complex` is a `struct`, not a `class`, which is has all manner of performance implications, and may be interested to look at the [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/Complex.cs) for it. From a brief look,`struct` seems the only relevant difference, since you are only assembling and adding and multiplying Complex numbers (Numerics' division will be more efficient (no SQRT), but I can see any use here).